# PostgreSQL INSERT bigint[] Array quote syntax

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I need to `UPDATE` existing rows with numeric arrays. I'm stuck on the syntax in regards to quotes (I think) currently. Here are the queries I have tried...

**Test 1**

```
WITH update_table_1 (id,column_b) AS 
(VALUES (1,'{22}'), (72,'{29, 5}')) 
UPDATE table_1 SET id = up.id, column_b = up.column_b FROM update_table_1 up 
WHERE up.id = table_1.id;
```

**Test 2**

```
WITH update_table_1 (id,column_b) AS 
(VALUES (1,'{"22"}'), (72,'{"29","5"}')) 
UPDATE table_1 SET id = up.id, column_b = up.column_b FROM update_table_1 up 
WHERE up.id = table_1.id;
```

**Test 3**

```
WITH update_table_1 (id,column_b) AS 
(VALUES (1,{22}), (72,{29, 5})) 
UPDATE table_1 SET id = up.id, column_b = up.column_b FROM update_table_1 up 
WHERE up.id = table_1.id;
```

**Test 4**

```
WITH update_table_1 (id,column_b) AS 
(VALUES (1,{22}), (72,{"29","5"})) 
UPDATE table_1 SET id = up.id, column_b = up.column_b FROM update_table_1 up 
WHERE up.id = table_1.id;
```

Comment: Use casts: `'{1,2}'::bigint[]`

Comment: @DanielVérité Thank you, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use casts, the array[] constructor, or both:

```
select '{1,2}'::bigint[];
select array[1,2];           -- this is an int[]
select array[1,2]::bigint[];
```

Else, Postgres will (correctly) complain about unknown operators for types and the like.

Comment: The manual is actually rather lax on mentioning this; the relevant page would seem to be [Section 8.15 Arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html), which just has this parenthetical comment: "(These kinds of array constants are actually only a special case of the generic type constants discussed in [Section 4.1.2.7](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC). The constant is initially treated as a string and passed to the array input conversion routine. An explicit type specification might be necessary.)"